# Xamarin android player not working properly

Tags: xamarin-android-player

Xamarin android player stopped working suddenly and not responding in any way, done uninstall and installed again after installation i was trying to download Nexus4 kitkat but first of all its not even opens the player. Can please anyone help me with this??
ThankYou in Advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is forum about questions/answers of problems related to programming. It is not a support forum android apps.

Answer (score 0):

**Xamarin Android Player is no longer supported.** https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player/

Since Microsoft acquired Xamarin they now recommend using the Android Emulator in Visual Studio https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/

Another option is to use Genymotion.
https://www.genymotion.com/